# Spacing before a HTML Horizontal Line

Tags: html, css, horizontal-line

I was setting up some signatures in HTML which will end up in Outlook. One issue I have is that when inserting a horizontal line, it inserts a large space above and a smaller space below the line. My issue is the very large space above the horizontal line. It's almost the size of a full break

```
<br>
```

If I manually edit the signature in Outlook by setting the spacing after the text that is just before the horizontal line it's okay, but I can't do this manually for the # of them I need to edit. Here is an example of my issue:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Online Editor Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <span style="font-size:12pt;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>This is a test</b></span></span></p>
    <hr style="height: 2px; width: 99%; background-color: #848484" />
    <p>
        <span style="font-size:10pt;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><b>Text under the line</b></span></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can tighten the text before or after the line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paragraph elements `<p>` have some natural padding anad marggin so try to add padding: 0 and margin: 0 to them

Comment: This seems to be the case in this question, but there might be [other issues](http://en.blog.improveit.com.br/articles/2008/09/27/margins-on-the-hr-tag-a-case-solved) that could be addressed.

Answer (score 3):

The `hr` and `p` elements have some padding/margins inserted by the by the browser. Add `margin: 0;` to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<hr style="height: 2px; width: 99%; margin:0 auto;line-height:2px;background-color: #848484"; border:0 none; />
```

OR

```
<hr style="height: 0; width: 99%; line-height:0;border-bottom:2px solid #848484; background:none;" />
```

[fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/UGQKQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Always good to start with a reset CSS and take it from there.

Useful link:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/